mousedown event cannot be triggered in chrome service_worker context
I am developing a simple chrome plugin for autofilling some fields in webpage.
manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "autofill",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "auto fill fields in webpage",
    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/mangosteen.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://*/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
    },
    "commands": {
        "execute-code": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+E",
                "mac": "Command+E"
            },
            "description": "Execute code in active tab"
        }
    }
}

As above, I have registered a shortcut Command+E to execute some js code:
service-worker.js
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
  if (command === "execute-code") {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.js" }, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {
          file: "autofill.js",
        });
      });
    });
  }
});

autofill.js
(function () {
  $('.select2-container.select2-dropdown').each(function () {
    // open dropdown
    $(this).find('.select2-choice').mousedown()

    // pick one
    let options = $('#select2-drop .select2-result.select2-result-selectable')
    $(options[1]).mouseup()
  })
})()

I want to auto pick an option for all https://github.com/select2/select2 component.
Everything is ok except that mousedown event cannot be triggered, so the dropdown cannot be opened, but I can execute above code normally in console, which is so weird, what went wrong? I would be grateful for any helpful suggestions you could offer。
Want I tried:
after debug, I can sure that mousedown event cannot be triggered in service-worker context.
Expecting:
mousedown event should be triggered, then I can pick an option from dropdown.
